# Avoid nester query in php cycle

Tags: php, jquery, join

I have these tables:

```
users
id_user | name | surname | country
```

And

```
photos
   id_photo | id_user | title
```

Every user could have several photos

I use this symple query:

```
Select * from User INNER JOIN Photos ON (users.id_user = photos.id_user)
```

I have a php cycle in a page and I want show only ONE row for every user.
How can I do if the users have many photos saved in the table?

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from User INNER JOIN Photos ON (users.id_user = photos.id_user) 
WHERE photos.id_photo = 1;
```

Comment: When replying with a code snippet, please consider adding a little explanation on how and why your code does answer the OP question.